# Integral $\int_0^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{3x^2}{4x^4+5x^2+2}\right) \frac{dx}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I tried to solve this integral on Brilliant earlier using an identity for improper integrals, but it turned out to be wrong. I did some research and found that this identity only works when our function has a "bounded anti-derivative" on our interval. Here is the integral in question:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac1x \arctan\left(\frac{3x^2}{4x^4+5x^2+2}\right) \mathrm dx$$

Here is where I found this identity:
https://brilliant.org/wiki/integration-tricks/

Scroll down to where it says "Inversions" to find it.

The question I had was why you had to have a bounded anti-derivative in order to make the substitution? I understand that the answer I received from doing this doesn't make sense (as I got the integral diverges), but I don't understand why. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I think the inversion would not affect convergence. If the original integral diverges then the integral after inversion diverges as well. Similarly, if the original integral converges  then the integral still converges after inversion.

Comment: I have hard time understanding what is the connection between the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac1x \arctan\left(\frac{3x^2}{4x^4+5x^2+2}\right) dx$$ and the trick "inversion", since I dont see  the integral anywhere on that page. Do you wish to solve the integral?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to solve the integral so I used the inversion method. I guess I probably did a wrong step in my work. From what I remember, I applied that rule and then used arctan(1/x) = pi/2 - arctan(x) when x>0. Maybe I couldn't use this here, as I then had the arctans cancel out.

Comment: Do you wish to see an approach without that substitution?

Comment: Sure, but could you try to approach it using the substitution as well and show if/why it doesn't work. Maybe my mistake was using the arctan(x) + arctan(1/x) = pi/2

Comment: Can this only be applied if the argument is literally just x or 1/x? I applied it here because I thought using 1/x would make this true, if you get what  i'm saying

Comment: The substitution $\frac{a}{x}$ (from what I have seen) works better if you want to play with symmetry, for example $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\arctan x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$ Here your ideea from the two above comments applies perfectly. Also this (one of my favourite) $$I=\int_0^{\infty}\ln x\frac{x^2 + 4}{x^4 +16}   dx$$ (use $\frac{4}{x} =t$). Unfortunately for your integral  I am unable to see why and how would it help. Let me know if I can clarify anything. 

Also if you want to draw some attention, you may change to a more attractive tilte, for example Integral and put the integral in latex form.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{3x^2}{1\color{blue}{+}4x^4+5x^2+1}=\frac{4x^2\color{blue}{-}x^2}{1\color{blue}{+}(4x^2+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{(4x^2+1)\color{blue}{-}(x^2+1)}{1\color{blue}{+}(4x^2+1)(x^2+1)}$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{(4x^2+1)\color{red}{-}(x^2+1)}{1\color{red}{+}(4x^2+1)(x^2+1)}\right)=\arctan(4x^2+1)\color{red}{-}\arctan(x^2+1)$$ Now you might notice why there was not needed any $\frac1x$ substitution. Also your integral becomes a [Frullani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral)-type integral, so:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(4x^2+1)-\arctan(x^2+1)}{x}dx=\left(\arctan (0) -\arctan (\infty ) \right)\ln \left(\frac12 \right) =\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$$